# Using "typedef" or "using" to define a structure - which is best?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, using

Sample structure:

```
typedef struct tagExportSettings
{
    COLORREF    crHeading{};
    COLORREF    crEvenBack{};
    COLORREF    crOddBack{};
    COLORREF    crHighlight{};
    COLORREF    crDate{};
    COLORREF    crEvent{};
    COLORREF    crEmpty{};
    COLORREF    crNotes{};

} EXPORT_SETTINGS_S;
```

Visual Assist says:

> `typedef` can be converted to `using` declaration.

Is there any real benefit of making this code change?

All my code in the software uses `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S` so I don't want to break that syntax.

Comment: This `typedef` pattern has roots in `C` (in `C` `struct` prefix has to be used to use struct symbol or can be replaced by typedef) and is obsolete in C++. `using` is C++ only. So answer should be obvious.

Comment: Not exactly in this context, but you can simply omit the `typedef` to achieve the same in c++.

Comment: Remove typedef and exportsettings. Use like a class.

Comment: Is your code a library you provide to clients? Is it C++ library or C library (looks like C)?

Comment: @MarekR Visual Studio Visual C++ Dialog application.

Comment: So if this is just application (no need to maintain source compatibility) which is C++ you should follow C++ patterns and avoid `C` patterns. So `eerorika` answer is IMO best approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even better is to use neither. One type name should be enough. Pick either `tagExportSettings` or `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S` and stick with it. Example:

```
struct tagExportSettings
{
    // ...
};
```

> But, 1. All my code in the software uses `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S`

As I said, pick either name. If you use `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S`, then name the class as `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S`:

```
struct EXPORT_SETTINGS_S
{
    // ...
};
```

If something still refers to `tagExportSettings`, then refactor the code to use the canonical name.

---

But more generally, `using` is preferred to `typedef` because it's more readable. There are at least two reasons for it:

1. With `typedef` syntax it isn't intuitive which is the old name and which is the new alias:

   ```
   typedef new_or_old old_or_new; // old_or_new is the new alias
   ```

   `using` is intuitive through familiar pattern of initialisation:

   ```
   using intuitively_alias = intuitively_old_name;
   ```
2. `typedef` syntax is difficult for a programmer to parse in case of compound names because the alias is "interleaved":

   ```
   // alias for void()
   typedef void function();
   using function = void();
   ```

Comment: But, 1. All my code in the software uses `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S` so I don't want to break that syntax now. And 2. if I strip the `tagExportSettings` it lists as an unnamed cryptic structure in the Visual Studio ClassView tab.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle you should update question with this information.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You are not supposed to just strip `tagExportSettings`. You are supposed to replace the whole `typedef` declaration with the code shown in this answer. The name of the `struct` should then show up as `EXPORT_SETTINGS_S`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing in C++, `using` is much better. For example, a template struct like this:

```
template <typename Tp>
struct WrapData
{
    const bool has_value = !std::is_void<Tp>::value;
    typename std::conditional<std::is_void<Tp>::value, uint8_t, Tp>::type value;
    // more properties
};
```

You can use `typedef` or `using` like this:

```
using void_t = WrapData<void>;
using int_t = WrapData<int>;

// same as using
typedef WrapData<int> tp_int_t;
```

But only `using` can work if use template:

```
// // compile error
// template<typename Tp>
// typedef WrapData<Tp> TpWrapData;

template<typename Tp>
using UsWrapData = WrapData<Tp>;
```

Comment: identifiers starting with `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming pure C++, it depends if you're using raw pointers or not. If you don't, then just define the struct under proper name without either `typedef` or `using`.

```
struct EXPORT_SETTINGS_S
    {...
```

If you're using raw pointers a lot and in Windows, it's customary to define not just alias but a pointer type as well:

```
typedef struct tagExportSettings
{
    ...
} EXPORT_SETTINGS_S, *LPEXPORT_SETTINGS_S;
```

That certainly matters only if you are accustomed to [`LPXXX` "types"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader). If you're a `*` person, then there's no need.

Neither of those are a clear-cut case for `using`.

Comment: if you want an alias for pointer there is still no need to `typedef` the struct itself or `typedef` at all. Just do `using EXPORT_SETTINGS_PTR = EXPORT_SETTINGS_S*;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, but it's more important to stick to platform convention rather than starting a better one and ending with no convention at all. Because the whole point of a convention is to have only one.

Comment: what convention do yuo mean? A convention that forces to write outdated and obfuscated code isnt very useful

Comment: the answer suggests that using an alias for pointers would be a reason to alias also the type itself. Thats wrong. On the other hand introducing an alias for the pointer type is exactly what `using` is for.  No need for an argument

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The answer states what is WIN32 custom. Nothing else.